# get web application classes with javaagent?

Tags: java, instrumentation, javassist

is there a way to retrieve classes loaded or classloader of the web application?

for example if i use this code :

```
ClassLoader c=getClass().getClassLoader();
logmsg("c="+c);
URLClassLoader u=(URLClassLoader)c;
URL[] urls=u.getURLs();
for (URL i : urls) {
    logmsg("url: "+i);
}
```

Im getting librairies used by the agent not the web application

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Reflections](https://code.google.com/p/reflections/) package. It uses javassist to provide runtime class meta-data lookup. In order to locate the correct classpath URLs, it provides a helper class [ClasspathHelper](http://reflections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/reflections/javadoc/apidocs/org/reflections/util/ClasspathHelper.html). ClasspathHelper provides a couple of static methods that return the URLs for WebApps by passing a ServletContext of the target WebApp:

```
static URL forWebInfClasses(javax.servlet.ServletContext servletContext)
static Set<URL> forWebInfLib(javax.servlet.ServletContext servletContext)
```